# Form validation library

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, html, validation, form

**Background:**

After reading [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) thought provoking book I decided to write a small library as an exercise.

```
goog.require('goog.structs.Map');


var MyModule = {};

MyModule.FormHelper = {
  /** @type {?Element} */
  form: null,
  /** @type {goog.structs.Map<string, string>} */
  errors: {},

  /** @param {!Element} element */
  init: function(formElement) {
    this.form = formElement;
  },

  /**
   * @param {!Element} element
   * @return {!Array<goog.structs.Map<string, Object>>}
   */
  getElementAttributes: function(element) {
    if (!element) return [];
    return [].slice.call(element.attributes).map(function(attr) {
      return {[attr.name]: attr.value};
    });
  },

  /**
   * @param {string} filterOn
   * @return {!Array<!Element>}
   */
  filterElements: function(filterOn) {
    return [].slice.call(this.form.elements).filter(function(element) {
      return element.hasAttribute(filterOn);
    });
  }
};

MyModule.Form = Object.create(MyModule.FormHelper);

MyModule.Form.validate = function() {
  /** @type {!Array<!Element>} */
  var elements = this.getRequiredElements();
  elements.reduce(function(map, element) {
    if (element.value == '') {
      map[element.name] = 'Required field cannot be empty';
    }
    return map;
  }, this.errors);
};

MyModule.Form.getRequiredElements = function() {
  return this.filterElements('required');
};

MyModule.createForm = function(name) {
  /** @type {!Element} */
  var formElement = document.forms[name];
  if (!formElement) {
    throw new Error('Form not found.');
  }
  var form = Object.create(MyModule.Form);
  form.init(formElement);
  return form;
};

var contactForm;
var callback = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  contactForm.validate();
  console.log(contactForm.errors);
}

window.onload = function () {
  contactForm = MyModule.createForm('ContactForm');
  contactForm.form.addEventListener("submit", callback, false);  //Modern browsers
}
```

I am using Google [closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) for type checking and advance code optimizations.

I want to check if I am following a good object oriented design and practices?

**Update 1**

```
;(function(global, doc, lib) {
  var Form = {};

  Form.create = function(name) {
    var form = doc.forms[name];
    if (!form) {
      throw new Error('Form not found.');
    }
    this.formElement = form;
  };

  Form.elements = function() {
    return this.formElement.elements;
  };

  Form.filter = function(attr) {
    return [].slice.call(this.elements()).filter(function(element) {
      return element.hasAttribute(attr);
    });
  };

  Form.getAttributes = function(element) {
    if (!element) return [];
    return [].slice.call(element.attributes).map(function(attr) {
      return {[attr.name]: attr.value};
    });
  };

  Form.validate = function(formName) {
    var elements = this.filter('required');
    elements.reduce(function(error, element) {
      if (element.value == '') {
        error[element.name] = 'Required field cannot be empty';
      }
      return error;
    }, this.errors);
  };

  lib.validate = function(formName) {
    var form = Object.create(Form);
    form.create(formName);
    form.errors = [];
    form.validate();
    return form;
  };

})(window, document, window.lib || (window.lib = {}));

window.onload = function() {
  console.log(lib);
  console.log(lib.validate('foo').errors);
};
```

Comment: Are you using ES6 or not?

Comment: @gcampbell no! not in near future.

Comment: `{[attr.name]: attr.value }` is an ES6 object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Global variables

I know this isn't part of the module and probably just throwaway code, but you should restructure the module usage to avoid making global variables contactForm and callback:

```
    window.onload = function () {
      var contactForm = MyModule.createForm('ContactForm');
      contactForm.form.addEventListener("submit", function onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        contactForm.validate();
        console.log(contactForm.errors);
      }, false);  //Modern browsers
    }
```

### Organization of properties between prototypes

I'm not sure why you'd divide up methods and properties between `FormHelper` and `Form`, as they seem to perform very similar functionality. I'd combine them into a single `Form` object; that's the only prototype you need.

This may seem too simple, but your module solves a simple problem. A more complicated module that would benefit from delegation between multiple prototypes would be one that has multiple types of `Element` prototypes, with some validation functions shared between `Element`s and some specific to particular types.

### `form` prototype property

I don't think you need/want the `form: null` property on the prototype object. Even though `init` is a method of the prototype, it's assigning `form` to the base object (also named `form`) that exists in the submit handler, and that's what you want - a shared `form` property would make multiple `Form`s impossible.

Also, a subjective point: I'd rename this property to `formElement` or just `element`, since there are too many `form`s and `Form`s running around this code.

---

I hope this helps! Kyle Simpson's YDKJS books made me think as well, and with ES6 classes growing more common every day, I often wonder how this explicitly prototype-based JavaScript style can coexist with the classes Simpson discredited.

Comment: Hi can you please provide some more insight? is this code production ready?

Comment: What kind of additional info are you interested in? I would say the code isn't production ready until you fix the first issue I described, as modules shouldn't pollute the global namespace. The internal structure isn't a deal-breaker if the module works, but splitting it into Form and FormHelper makes it somewhat trickier to maintain.

Comment: In that case I need to update my question then.

Comment: Let me know when you do, and I'll take a look and post a new answer.

Comment: Updated, but I think I am getting more confused about I need an object or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code gets to the heart of the matter, and we start to see how simple this module is - really, it's just validating `required` form elements. You could also remove `getAttributes`, since it's currently unused.

As for your question, no, you don't really need an object, especially if the library is going to stay this simple. You could simplify the code by:

- taking out `Form` entirely
- deleting `Form.create`, and
- converting all other `Form` functions into private functions that are called by each other and by `lib.validate` directly.

Your current object-oriented approach would come in handy in a few situations, but for each you'd have to export `Form` itself as `lib.Form`, not just `lib.validate`.

One situation is if you ever wanted to extend this base `Form` into different types of `Form`s; then the prototype delegation would allow these different types to share common `Form` functions.

Another situation is if you changed the API to be more jQuery-like: users would be able to wrap a form in a `Form` object once, then call `validate` on it multiple times. This is a very different API (and makes the most sense for libraries like jQuery that do a lot of different things). The disadvantage of this approach is that it's more verbose (`var form = lib.Form('foo'); console.log(form.validate().errors)` versus just `console.log(lib.validate().errors)`), while the advantage is that `createForm` doesn't have to be called every time `validate` is.

One small note: simple functions like `Form.elements` can be defined via "getter" functions for a slightly cleaner look:

```
Object.defineProperty(Form, "elements", { get: function () { this.formElement.elements; } });

Form.filter = function(attr) {
    // NOTE: this.elements instead of this.elements()
    return [].slice.call(this.elements).filter(function(element) {
      return element.hasAttribute(attr);
    });
};
```

Comment: Regarding `elements` access I would go for [UFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) wdyt?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I've usually gone with methods (in this case, named `getElements`), but sometimes these feel like excessive boilerplate. You also have a `formElement` property, but it could be considered private, i.e. not one of `Form`'s "services".